# duplicate values in hash

Tags: perl, hash

Item1 : Box1
Item2 : Box1

Item3 : Box2
Item4 : Box2

I have an output in the form of a hash(listed above)
I want to process it so that output looks like to be

Box1 = {Item1, Item2}
Box2 = {Item3, Item4}

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I am sorry if it was not clear. I am looking for the code for that change in perl

Comment: It's still not clear. You haven't shown a hash, just some plain text. Are you trying to print a hash, read text into a hash, read text into a hash and print it in a different format, or something totally different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the most I could make based on your requirements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %items = (
    Item1 => 'Box1',
    Item2 => 'Box1',

    Item3 => 'Box2',
    Item4 => 'Box2',
);

my %boxes = ();

foreach my $item_name ( keys %items ){
    push @{ $boxes{ $items{$item_name} } }, $item_name;
}

print "Boxes: ".Dumper( \%boxes );
```

and prints:

```
Boxes: $VAR1 = {
          'Box1' => [
                      'Item1',
                      'Item2'
                    ],
          'Box2' => [
                      'Item4',
                      'Item3'
                    ]
        };
```

Comment: this is what exactly i was looking for...thankyou

Comment: and sorry for the incomplete question :(

Comment: cool, I'm glad I could help